# Multiple Updating not workiing on workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I have a database SQL table looking like this
[the database table][image: 1]

So I'm trying to update this table simultaneously, such that one query updates multiple columns in multiple rows at once. The script looks like this

```
INSERT INTO teams
        (id, team_name, matches_played, won, lost, points, goals_for, goals_against, goal_difference, last_match)
        VALUES 
            ('10', 'Manchester City', '3', '1', '', '3', '2', '0', '0', 'W'),
            ('5', 'Westham', '2', '', '1', '3', '0', '2', '-1', 'L')
      
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            team_name = VALUES(team_name),
            matches_played = VALUES(matches_played),
            won = VALUES(won),
            lost = VALUES(lost),
            points = VALUES (points),
            goals_for = VALUES(goals_for),
            goals_against = VALUE(goals_against),
            goal_difference = VALUE(goal_difference),
            last_match = VALUES(last_match);
```

My issue is. This code works perfectly on XAMPP MySQL server but not on workbench. What might the issue be?

Comment: What does the error message say

Comment: You do realise that Workbench connects to your XAMPP mariaDB dont you . Unless you are doing the Workench stuff on a different machine

Comment: Nope. I was trying to connect it to remotemysql.com not localhost. Thank you guys for pitching in but I've found the solution. The problem was that databases in remotemysql.com do not accept entry of empty values. 
For example, 
('10', 'Manchester City', '3', '1', ' ', '3', '2', '0', '0', 'W'),
Wrong

('10', 'Manchester City', '3', '1', NULL, '3', '2', '0', '0', 'W'),
Right

The problem doesn't show up on localhost though. Only when working with remotemysql.com
Thanks for trying to help guys